# How to add any numbers that are divisible by 3 to a new array?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes in an array full of numbers. It should loop through the array but I want it to add any numbers that are divisible by 3 to a new array called three. Once that takes place, I simply want to return the threes array. Here's what I have so far.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

function loveTheThrees(numeros) {
  for(var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++)
}
  var threes;
  //%3
  return threes;
var ok = loveTheThrees(numbers);

//line 1 shows the array numbers
//line 3 I have written a function called loveTheThrees
//line 4 is looping through the array but I want to add any numbers that are divisible by 3 to a new array called threes
//I also want to return the threes array after I have added all the numbers that are divisble by 3
```

Comment: Looks like you already know about remainder operator, what is the hard part here?

Answer (score -1):

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
function loveTheThrees(numeros) {
  var threes = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
    if(numeros[i]%3 == 0) threes.push(numeros[i]);
  }
  return threes;
}
var ok = loveTheThrees(numbers);
```

Ok is now an array of all numbers divisible by 3.